# Encapsulate Web requests per model

Tags: web-services, flutter, dart, service, encapsulation

I'm new to Dart and Flutter, and I'm using a `Webservice` pattern I found on a blog that seemed clever at the time, but as I move through development it seems more restrictive than it's worth. The goal here is to fetch json from a server, automatically parse and instantiate it based on the `model` fetched.

I've already had to stretch the class in order to add `headers` and `body`, now I need to fetch an individual instance of the `event`, but I can't make that request with the stateless static `all` method. The goal is to have a flexible encapsulated service that can make requests and parse them based on `model` implementations.

If it's not clear, I have the `event_id`, and now I want to fetch the details of that single event.

Here's the medium post: https://medium.com/flutter-community/fetching-data-in-flutter-and-displaying-in-listview-ec1bb72af22c

The `Resource` class:

```dart
class Resource<T> {
  final String url;
  String body;
  Map<String, String> headers;
  T Function(Response response) parse;

  setBody(String jsonString) {
    this.body = jsonString;
  }

  setHeaders(Map<String, String> headerMap) {
    this.headers = headerMap;
  }

  Resource({this.url, this.parse});
}
```

The Webservice class:

```dart
class Webservice<T> {
  Map<String, String> headers;
  String body;

  Webservice({this.headers, this.body});

  Future<T> load<T>(Resource<T> resource) async {
    resource.setHeaders(this.headers);
    final response = await http.get(resource.url, headers: resource.headers);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return resource.parse(response);
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load data!');
    }
  }

  Future<T> post<T>(Resource<T> resource) async {
    resource.setHeaders(this.headers);
    resource.setBody(this.body);

    final response = await http.post(
      resource.url,
      headers: resource.headers,
      body: resource.body,
    );
    print(response.statusCode);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return resource.parse(response);
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to post to endpoint!');
    }
  }
}
```

and one implementation:

```
class Event {
  final String title;
  final int id;

  Event({this.title, this.id});

  factory Event.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Event(
        title: json['title'] as String,
        id: json['event_id'] as int,
      );

  static Resource<List<Event>> get all {
    return Resource(
      url: Constants.baseURI + '/events',
      parse: (response) {
        final result = json.decode(response.body);
        Iterable list = result;
        return list.map((model) => Event.fromJson(model)).toList();
      },
    );
  }
```

and the client code:

```dart
Map<String, String> headers = {
        HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: this.user.token.token
      };
      Webservice(headers: headers).load(Event.all).then((events) => {
            setState(() => {_events = events})
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was fairly obvious once I'd written out the problem. Though I'm still interested in others' opinions/takes on a `Webservice`.

Basically, I already have an model object, in the example case, an `Event`. So I make the method non-static, and just call it as is. In this example I'm building a new Event object because my endpoint returns what I need, but you could see a `build` function or something to help flesh it out.

non-static `one` function on the model, the key here is the `Webservice` is now inside this method:

```dart
Future<Event> one() async {
    await Webservice()
        .load(
      Resource(
        url: Constants.baseURI + '/event/' + this.id.toString(),
        parse: (response) {
          final result = json.decode(response.body);
          return Event.fromJson(result);
        },
      ),
    )
        .then((event) {
      return event;
    });
  }
```

Then the client code:

```dart
this.event.one().then((event) {\*...*\}
```

and Bob's your uncle. The `Webservice` stays the same.